# Unable to delete value from set?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, set

```js
let obj = {
  name: 'ajay'
};
let obj1 = {
  name: 'sham'
};
let newSet = new Set();
newSet.add(obj);
newSet.add(obj1);
console.log(newSet.has('name'));
console.log(newSet.delete('ajay'));
```

Comment: An object is not a string

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding how the `Map` data structure works. You can read about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've added two *objects* to your `Set`.

Then, you try to look up a *string* `"name"`, but as long as you haven't done something like this...

```
newSet.add("name");
```

...that call will return `false`.
The objects inside Set have a key `"name"`, but the `Set` itself isn't.

Then, the same issue happening with `"ayay"`.

But if you try to look up or delete your objects from the `Set`, it will work:

```js
let obj = {
  name: 'ajay'
};
let obj1 = {
  name: 'sham'
};

let newSet = new Set();
newSet.add(obj);
newSet.add(obj1);

console.log(newSet.has(obj)); //true
console.log(newSet.delete(obj1)); //true

newSet.forEach(elem => console.log(elem)); //{name:"ayay"}
```